# Django Rest Framework custom validation function on ForeignKey field is not called

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelSerializer` that has a `ForeignKey` field. This is the code for the model:

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='attendance_times')
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

and this is the serializer:

```
class AttendanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate_employee(self, value):
        try:
            Employee.objects.get(pk=value)
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            Employee.objects.create(pk=value)
        return value

    class Meta:
        model = Attendance
        fields = ('employee', 'datetime')
```

the problem is when I send a post request to create a new object, the function `validate_employee` is not called and the serializer returns a validation error saying:

> Invalid pk "1321" - object does not exist.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong? Is there another validator that is being called before my validator?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that happen before you the `validate_<field>` is called.

In particular, the field itself will perform an initial validation check and cast the incoming data into Python object. With `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` it'll check the associated model and return the instance.

Comment: Is there a way to override that validation? I want to create a new object if it does not exist @linovia

Comment: Have your own field and override https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L251

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to call `save()` function after creating the instance.

```
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        employee = Employee.objects.create(pk=value)
        employee.save()
    return value
```